# Qt QGraphicsScene dynamic GUI elements like containers

Tags: c++, qt, qgraphicsscene, qgraphicsitem

I'm using QGraphicsScene and I want to create gui elements.

How do I/should I create a list container i.e. inventory in a game context.

See HERE

[image]

For an example of what I mean. There is an inventory widget at the bottom that can be dynamically populated.

Are there any container classes like the standard list widgets but for QGraphicsScene instead?

Right now the only way I can see is to draw a 'rectangle' and manually draw and manage 'squares' on top of it... which wouldn't be a container.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every `QGraphicItem` is effectively a container because every item can be optionally parented to a `QGraphicsItem`. When you do that, the parent affects all its children...if the parent is moved, the children move with it. If a transform, visibility, or opacity are set on the parent, those changes apply to the children as well.

Basically, your understanding is correct; you would create a parent `QGraphicsItem` that draws a container outline, and then you would have children that each draw their icons or whatever is appropriate.

Alternately, you can use widgets in a `QGraphicsScene`, so all of the widget-based containers are available. If that's the route you want to go, then look at the `QGraphicsWidget` class.

This is a complex subject, but hopefully this will get you started.

Comment: Cool, I was looking at QGraphicsWidget, adding a QGraphicsLinearLayout containing QGraphicsWidgets... but I want to add QGraphicsItems. Any idea how?

Comment: Ok, I got it. I just sub classed QGraphicsWidget, added a QGraphicsLinearLayout and then added other items to it. Not as elegant as I would have hoped but ok.

Comment: You have less control over the appearance of widgets in a scene than with custom graphics items, but they're certainly convenient.

Comment: How do you mean? Like a nine patch graphic would probably be better?

Comment: It depends on what you're using. For example, if you use a QToolButton or QPushButton, those draw themselves with a distinctive style. If you create your own custom graphics item, you can draw whatever you want, but the downside is that you have to write the code to draw it. I'm not particularly a good artists, so using most anything built-in is a better choice for me. It just depends on what look and feel you're going for. There's no right or wrong answer.

Comment: Oh ok, I actually already had custom graphics items from my tiles which worked quite nicely with this, I might have to add these to buttons though. But for the main container itself, yeah, it's either basic or a lot of code.